# Matching vector of default values using match.arg() with or without error [R]

Tags: r, function, arguments, match, evaluation

I want to write a function that applies one of two different statistical methods to its input.
In the process, I noticed some behavior of different functions that I do not understand.
The function I want to write should have the following properties:

- it should have a vector as a default value (so the user can see which methods are available)
- if the argument is left at the default value, then the first of the two methods should be used
- if the user *manually* supplies a vector of methods, then the function should give an error

Basically, I want the function to behave like `cor` does in R. There, you have a default value `method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")`, and the functions calculated the Pearson correlation if `method` isn't specified. If the user asks for several methods at once, the function returns an error.

From looking at `cor`, this appears to be done using `match.arg(method)`. This behavior is illustrated here:

```
x <- y <- 1:5

cor(x, y, method="pearson")
# = 1
cor(x, y, method="kendall")
# = 1
cor(x, y, method=c("pearson","kendall"))
# gives an error
```

I tried writing my own function, also using `match.arg(method)`, but I realized that the result is somehow different.
Even when choosing a vector for `method`, the function doesn't terminate with an error, but returns the results of the first method.

This is illustrated here:

```
myfun <- function(x, method=c("add","multiply")){
  method <- match.arg(method)
  if(method=="add") return(sum(x))
  if(method=="multiply") return(prod(x))
}

x <- 1:5

myfun(x, method="add")
# = 15
myfun(x, method="multiply")
# = 120
myfun(x, method=c("add","multiply"))
# = 15
```

I don't understand this behavior, and I would be glad if you could help me out here.
From my attempts on Google, I realize that it might be related to non-standard evaluation, but I can't put two and two together just yet.

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

I could also re-phrase my question:

What powerful sorcery does `cor` do that it returns the Pearson correlation when `method` is not supplied, but that it returns an error when `method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")` is explicitly specified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `choices` and `args` are the same in `match.arg`, then the first element is returned. Otherwise `arg` has to be length 1. From `match.arg`:

> Since default argument matching will set arg to choices, this is allowed as an exception to the ‘length one unless several.ok is TRUE’ rule, and returns the first element.

```
match.arg(c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
## [1] "pearson"
match.arg(c("pearson", "kendall"), c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
## Error in match.arg(c("pearson", "kendall"), c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")) : 
##  'arg' must be of length 1
```

You can get your desired behavior using a dummy argument:

```
myfun <- function(x, method=c("add","multiply","other.return.error")){
  method <- match.arg(method)
  if("other.return.error" %in% method) stop("this option should not be used")
  if(method=="add") return(sum(x))
  if(method=="multiply") return(prod(x))
}
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the behavior of `cor` and `myfun` differ because I tested for a two-element vector, where `cor` returns an error because its default argument is of length 3, and `myfun` runs without error because its default argument is of length 2?

Comment: The "desired" behavior was actually not part of the question. I solved that myself, simply by checking if `method` is supplied using `missing(method)` and printing an error using `stop` if it was supplied with length > 1. That way I don't need a dummy argument that would show in man pages as well.

Comment: Yes, the behavior of `cor` and `myfun` differ because of the length of default arguments. And I get that the desired behavior was not part of the question. I added a solution not necessarily for you, but for other people who may find this question and have not found a satisfying solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

The main question was answered by @shadow (see above).

Another way of getting the desired behavior for `myfun` is to perform a check if `method` is supplied or not and printing an error if it was *explicitly* supplied with more than one element.

```
myfun <- function(x, method=c("add","multiply")){
  if(!missing(method) & length(method)>1) stop("Only one 'method' allowed.")
  method <- match.arg(method)
  if(method=="add") return(sum(x))
  if(method=="multiply") return(prod(x))
}

x <- 1:5

myfun(x)
# = 15
myfun(x, method="add")
# = 15
myfun(x, method="multiply")
# = 120
myfun(x, method=c("add","multiply"))
# gives error
```

This circumvents the exception in `match.arg` pointed out by @shadow by which supplying a vector to the function may *not* cause an error.
Instead, this error is given right away.